# React Ant Design Charts

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to draw two *Gradients area plot* in one page with two sets of data I tried

```
            const config = {
                data,
                xField: 'date',
                yField: 'value',
                //...
            };
            const config1 = {
                data1,
                xField: 'date',
                yField: 'value',
                //...
            };
...
//render return

                <ProCard style={{ margin: "20px 20px" }}
                    tabs={{
                    }}
                >
                    <ProCard.TabPane key="tab1" tab="require" >
                        <Area style={{heigh:"200px"}}{...config} />
                    </ProCard.TabPane>
                    <ProCard.TabPane key="tab2" tab="consume">
                        <Area style={{heigh:"200px"}} {...config1} />
                    </ProCard.TabPane>
                </ProCard>
```

but this doesn't work out.

how can i fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to divide your page into `two parts` and then use the code to render your `area plots`. You can do this using `CSS Flex` as follows:

```
<div className={styles.splitScreen}>
 <div className={styles.topPane}>
    {/* plot first area chart here */}
    <Area {...config} />
 </div>
 <div className={styles.bottomPane}>
   {/* plot second area chart here */}
   <Area {...config1} />
</div>
```

styles object:

```
splitScreen: {
    display: 'flex';
    flexDirection: 'row';
},
topPane: {
    width: '50%',
},
bottomPane: {
    width: '50%',
},
```

Only if you need them to be side-by-side, use `flexDirection: 'row'`

Reference link: [CSS Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)